# Performing a MATCH on all nodes on a path

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is it somehow possible to use a `MATCH` pattern inside the [`ALL` function](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/1.8/query-function.html#functions-all) (using v1.8)?

What I am trying to do is the following: I am `MATCH`ing a path `p = (a)-->(b)-->(c)-->(d)`. However, all nodes along this path must have an additional incoming relationship `r` from some node. Let me try to make this clear in ASCII:

```
(a)-->(b)-->(c)-->(d)
       ^     ^     ^
       |r    |r    |r
      ( )   ( )   ( )
```

Can I somehow use the `ALL` function for that or do I have to add additional `MATCH` patterns like this:

```
START ...
MATCH (a)-->(b)-->(c)-->(d)..., ()-[:r]->(b), ()-[:r]->(c), ...
RETURN ...
```

***Update:***

Here is an example in the [Neo4j console](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=oo5ikf):

```
START n=node(0) 
CREATE (a), (b), (c), (d), (e),
n-[:rel1]->a, n-[:rel1]->b, n-[:rel1]->d, n-[:rel1]->e,
a-[:rel2]->b-[:rel3]->d, a-[:rel2]->c-[:rel3]->e

START n=node(0) 
MATCH n -[:rel1]-> x -[:rel2]-> y -[:rel3]-> z, ()-[:rel1]->y, ()-[:rel1]->z 
RETURN z
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this using WHERE ALL, like this:

```
START n=node(0) 
MATCH path = n -[:rel1]-> x -[:rel2]-> y -[:rel3]-> z 
WHERE ALL(n in tail(nodes(path)) WHERE ()-[:rel1]->n) 
RETURN z
```

tail(nodes(path)) returns all nodes in the path except the first one. In your example, the start node was not connected with a rel1 relationship, so nothing was returned. If you want to do it like your text explains it, just drop the tail part.

Was this what you were looking for?

Comment: Nice! Thats what I was looking for. I've edited the question concerning the `TAIL`-part to clarify the problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You have any idea how the two solutions (either using `ALL` or using a combination of `MATCH` patterns) differ in performance?

Comment: The WHERE solution is always preferable to the MATCH, in terms of speed.